# Pandas Dataframe reindexing issue

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
           value
 objectID  
 ab798     54.68
 ab799     45.98 
 ab800     38.79
 etc..     etc..
```

where "value" is accesible as a column but "objectID" isn't, it's as if the DF has been indexed by "objectID". I want to have objectID be a column header like value and be able to access all of its rows (ab798, ab799, etc...) by calling pd.objectID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the index

```
df.reset_index()
```

Or, you can access it as an index:

```
df.index.values
```